# iOS14 UICollectionView Not Displaying Properly

Tags: uicollectionview, ios14

After upgrading to XCode12 and iOS14 I have an issue in one collection view which does not display as it did when compiling for iOS 13.6.  The order of the cells is wrong and the spacing/dimensions are as well.  Please see the picture (top, in the oval).  In the iOS13.6 build, the cells were equally spaced, did not overlap, and were in a different order.  This happens both on the simulator as well as on the actual device.

[image]

The code has not changed at all (still uses the delegates).

Does anyone have any clue?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Potential Bug in UICollectionview in iOS14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64029284/potential-bug-in-uicollectionview-in-ios14)

Comment: No, because it is the same question I posed in a much better way....

Comment: Why are you posting the same question twice? You should close one of them.

Comment: A better explanation with comparative examples can be found here: [Potential Bug in UICollectionview in iOS14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64029284/potential-bug-in-uicollectionview-in-ios14)

Comment: I have posted an answer in the link above